# Use Azure Functions as custom activity in ADFv2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to somehow package and execute already written azure function as a custom activity in azure data factory?

My workflow is next:

I want to use azure function (which is doing some data processing) in ADF pipeline as a custom activity. This custom activity is just one of the activities in pipeline but its key to be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow package and execute already written azure
>   function as a custom activity in azure data factory?

As I know, there is no way to do that so far. In my opinion, you do not need to package the Azure Function. I suggest you using [Web Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) to invoke the endpoint of your Azure Function which could merge into previous pipeline nicely.

Comment: Hi Jay. I'm just trying to implement this what you said and I'll keep you posted. As far as I can see it totally makes sense and I think this should totally works :)